# Is there a way to keep keyboard open when tapped outside textfield and keyboard in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, keyboard

Is there a way to keep keyboard open when tapped outside textfield and keyboard? When tapped outside it gets automatically dismissed. I want to keep it open till I close it by code.
The thing is that I suggesting some words for textfield and when user taps on that suggestion I don't it to close the keyboard because users want to add words continuously.

Comment: If user tap outside of textField and keyboard is open and user type something, than nothing will happen. So it is not good user experience. Rather keep it as it is and put your code inside done button of keyboard event.

Comment: please can you show your code cause normally it doesn't happened whithout focus

Comment: The thing is that I suggesting some words for textfield and when user taps on that suggestion I don't it to close the keyboard because users want to add words continuously.

Answer (score 0):

You can request a new focus every time the user taps on everything else on the screen ( `Scaffold` ):

```
final focusNode = FocusNode();
final shouldAlwysFocusOnTextField = true;

GestureDetector(
 onTap: () {
   if(shouldAlwysFocusOnTextField) {
     focusNode.requestFocus();
   }
  },
 child: Scaffold(/*...*/)
 ),
```

and assign that `focusNode` to your `TextField`:

```
TextField(
 focusNode: focusNode,
),
```